# Sempre devo usar o Navigation.PopAsync()?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-forms

Estou iniciando o aprendizado usando o Xamarin Forms. No meu caso, estou fazendo alguns testes com uma aplicação para Android.

Fazendo um paralelo com Windows Phone, quando eu navego de uma pagina A para a página B, e depois pressiono o botão Back do WP, ele remove a pagina da pilha corretamente.

No android existe este conceito de Push e Pop nas páginas. Minha pergunta é: sempre devo usar o método Navigation.PopAsync()? Ou basta eu usar os proprios botões de navegação do aparelho para voltar as páginas? No caso de ter que usar o Navigation.PopAsync(), devo colocá-lo no evento OnDisappearing()?

Abraços.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende. No **Android** e **UWP** temos botões físicos que conseguem efetuar a navegação e essa navegação desempilha as páginas. Já no **iOS** não temos esse botão, sendo assim, caso você não esteja num container `NavigationPage`, a seta de navegação que fica na parte superior esquerda da tela, não aparecerá, e você deverá utilizar o `PopAsync`.

Sobre os eventos disparados no momento que um PopAsync é invocado (Tirado da própria documentação):

When the `PopAsync` method is invoked, the following events occur:

- The page calling PopAsync has its OnDisappearing override invoked.
- The page being returned to has its OnAppearing override invoked.
- The PopAsync task returns.

A documentação é bem completa, vale a pena dar uma olhada: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/